# Add IdentityUserClaim Navigation to IdentityUser<int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, identity, .net-5

I'm trying to add **IdentityUserClaim** Navigation to my custom **IdentityUser< int >**, I tried many ways but it didn't work.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public List<AppUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}

public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{
}

public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
{
    //DBSets
}
```

If I run the app without migrations (I mean ef migration), then I got the following errors:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'AppUserId'.
>
> SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AppUserId], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue],
> [a].[UserId] FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a] WHERE [a].[UserId] =
> @__user_Id_0

And it's correct, there is no **AppUserId** column in **AspNetUserClaims** table.

And when I try to add migrations, then it adds a new column, which I won't it!

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        name: "AppUserId",
        table: "AspNetUserClaims",
        type: "int",
        nullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_AppUserId",
        table: "AspNetUserClaims",
        column: "AppUserId");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_AppUserId",
        table: "AspNetUserClaims",
        column: "AppUserId",
        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
}
```

How could I say to ef core that I need navigation on existing table relation?

[image: Current DB Schema]

Comment: Are you inheriting `IdentityDbContext`? Can you show the declaration of your derived `DbContext`, e.g. `class AppDbContext : ???`

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated the question with my ApplicationDbContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you have inherited the correct base `IdentityDbContext` with the correct generic arguments.

The problem thought is that the base class fluently configures the relationships with no navigation properties. Since the fluent configuration has higher priority than data annotations, the `[ForeignKey]` attribute is ignored and the navigation property is mapped to a **separate** relationship with its own FK.

So when you add navigation properties, you need also to override `OnModelCreating` and reconfigure the relationships **after** calling the base implementation, e.g.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<AppUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.UserClaims)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
}
```

Comment: The *key* word here is 'after'. I somehow missed that even though you have bolded the text.